# Laravel order by conditions eloquent or sql

Tags: sql, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I have these timestamp columns in database table - expiration, edit, created_at. I need to order by 'edit', if item 'expiration' date is bigger than today's date, else I need to order by 'created_at'.

I am trying something like this, but it isn't working correctly

```
$items = $items
->orderBy(DB::raw("CASE WHEN expiration >= $time THEN edit ELSE created_at END"), 'DESC')
->get();
```

or

```
$items = $items
->orderBy(DB::raw("CASE WHEN expiration >= $time THEN edit END"), 'DESC')
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->get();
```

Variable $time is correct, so my problem is in query.
Sample data:

```
id   name   created_at             expiration             edit
1.   it1    2015-03-16 15:42:40    0000-00-00 00:00:00    2015-03-16 15:42:40
2.   it2    2015-03-16 15:37:27    2015-03-16 00:00:00    2015-03-16 15:37:27
3.   it3    2015-03-16 12:36:50    2015-03-27 00:00:00    2015-03-16 14:52:19
```

And i need in order -> it3, it1, it2

Variable $time = 2015-03-17

Answer (score 7):

If u want to use 'Case' in order by clause there were 2 ways: 
Suppose users want to view "Order By" searching text 
i.e. "tamil nadu"

1:

```
->orderByRaw('case 
    when `title` LIKE "%tamil nadu%" then 1
    when `title` LIKE "%tamil%"  then 2 
    when `title` LIKE "%nadu%"  then 3 
    else 4 end');
```

---

2:
Pass your condition/case to order by clause

```
$searchText = explode(" ", $searchingFor);
$orderByRowCase = 'case when title LIKE "%tamil nadu%" then 1 ';
foreach ($searchText as $key => $regionSplitedText) {
   $Key += 2;
   $orderByRowCase .= ' when title LIKE "%' . $regionSplitedText . '%" then ' . $Key . '';
}
$orderByRowCase .= ' else 4 end';
```

(Your Laravel Query)

```
->orderByRaw($orderByRowCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->orderByRaw(
     "CASE WHEN expiration >= {$time} THEN edit ELSE created_at END DESC"
)
```

---

edit: your example shows that you want something else to what you asked for. The order of your set will be `it1, it2, it3`. To understand the behaviour try this:

```
select 
  name, 
  case when expiration >= '2015-03-17' then edit else created_at end as order_value 
from YOUR_TABLE 
order by case when expiration >= '2015-03-17' then edit else created_at end desc;
```

it will show you the value that is taken for the order by clause:

```
| name | order_value         |
| it1  | 2015-03-16 15:42:40 |
| it2  | 2015-03-16 15:37:27 |
| it3  | 2015-03-16 14:52:19 |
```

So, I suppose you in fact need to **order by IS_EXPIRED and then by the date**? Then you need two `case` clauses, or something like this:

```
->orderByRaw(
     "CASE WHEN expiration >= {$time} THEN concat('1 ', edit)
           ELSE concat('0 ',created_at) END DESC"
)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? If you really want to order by `X` or `Y`, then this is what you need. Maybe you want to order by `X` first, then by `Y`? Show sample data and expected output.

Comment: I added to my question some data

Comment: Check the edit - you got something wrong. Rephrase the question when you know what you need in the end.

Comment: I need order by edit date when NOT_EXPIRED and then by created_at

Comment: My first query is like your example I think

Comment: I need items in order by expiration date, if expiration date is bigger or equal today's date. And after that I need all other records ordered by created_at date

Comment: Then use 2 `cases` - one for EXPIRED condition, second for the date OR concatenate the two like in the edit.