# Laravel orderBy with column value error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to sort results by column value but it doesn't work

```
$users = Comment::select([
            'id',
            'comment',
            'user_name',
            'product_id',
            'rating',
            'country',
            'status',
            'pin',
            'created_at',
        ])->where('shop_name',$shop)->where('product_id', $id)->with('images')->orderByRaw("IF(product_url = 'customer')  DESC")->orderByRaw("product_url = manually ASC")->orderBy('pin', 'desc')->orderBy('rating', 'desc')->with('pages')->get();
```

I added this code

```
->orderByRaw("IF(product_url = 'customer')  DESC")
```

and I get this error

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  DESC,
>   product_url = manually ASC, `pin` desc, `rating` desc' at line 1 (SQL:
>   select `id`, `comment`, `user_name`, `product_id`, `rating`,
>   `country`, `status`, `pin`, `created_at` from `comments` where
>   `shop_name` =  and `product_id` =
>   order by IF(product_url = 'customer')  DESC, product_url
>   = manually ASC, `pin` desc, `rating` desc)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101242/laravel-order-by-conditions-eloquent-or-sql

Comment: You can include the `IF` result as a computed column, then order on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL `IF` function takes *three* arguments.

This expression is invalid:

```
  IF(product_url = 'customer')
```

because there is only one argument provided to the `IF()` function.

We could do this:

```
  IF(product_url = 'customer',1,0)
```

which is equivalent to the more ANSI-standards compliant

```
  CASE WHEN product_url = 'customer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

---

MySQL shorthand would also work

```
  ORDER BY product_url = 'customer'   DESC
```

which would be equivalent to

```
  ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN product_url = 'customer' THEN 1 
           WHEN product_url IS NOT NULL  THEN 0
           ELSE NULL
           END   DESC
```